# Prevent duplicate E-mail Google Spreadsheets script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

i'm currently able to send E-mail with Google Spreadsheets script. But my trigger and if condition didn't prevent E-mail sending as i wish :

Here is my code :
'''

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER");

  const h3 = 'SPP Proyek JIS Tanggal xx dari xxx';
  const headers = ws.getRange("A2:M2").getValues();
  const item = headers[0][4];
  const spec = headers[0][5];
  const sat = headers[0][6];
  const qty = headers[0][7];
  const price = headers[0][8];
  const total = headers[0][9];
  const tujuan = headers[0][10];

  const lr = ws.getLastRow();

  const tableRangeValues = ws.getRange(3, 5,lr-2,7).getDisplayValues();
  const trigger = ws.getRange(3, 1,lr-2).getValues();
  const statusEmail = ws.getRange(3, 13,lr-2).getValues();

  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email");
  htmlTemplate.h3 = h3;
  htmlTemplate.headers = headers;
  htmlTemplate.item = item;
  htmlTemplate.spec = spec;
  htmlTemplate.sat = sat;
  htmlTemplate.qty = qty;
  htmlTemplate.price = price;
  htmlTemplate.total = total;
  htmlTemplate.tujuan = tujuan;
  htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues;
  htmlTemplate.trigger = trigger;
  htmlTemplate.statusEmail = statusEmail;

  const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

  if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (statusEmail != 'EMAIL_SENT')); {

  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    "sistem.jis@gmail.com", 
    "Approval SPP Komersial", 
    "HTML Support",
    { htmlBody: htmlForEmail }
   );

  ws.getRange(3, 13,lr-2).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');

}
```

'''

and this is my sample file link :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13TKIhY7HmK3o-j98q45XXb2nwZzfYwyYn7EULhY_RJw/edit#gid=1216091331

it seems i have problem with the trigger and if condition code which i don't understand

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Defining `const trigger = ws.getRange(3, 1,lr-2).getValues();` returns you an array of type `[[FALSE], [true], [FALSE], [true]]`

- To make your code work you need to define a loop that iterates through each row (and trigger) invidually
- Also, remove the `;` from `if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (statusEmail != 'EMAIL_SENT')); {`

**Sample:**

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("MASTER");

  const h3 = 'SPP Proyek JIS Tanggal xx dari xxx';
  const headers = ws.getRange("A2:M2").getValues();
  const item = headers[0][4];
  const spec = headers[0][5];
  const sat = headers[0][6];
  const qty = headers[0][7];
  const price = headers[0][8];
  const total = headers[0][9];
  const tujuan = headers[0][10];
  const lr = ws.getLastRow();
  const tableRangeValues = ws.getRange(3, 5,lr-2,7).getDisplayValues();
  var data = ws.getRange(3, 1,lr-2,13).getDisplayValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    const trigger = data[i][0];
    const statusEmail = data[i][12];

    const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Email");
    htmlTemplate.h3 = h3;
    htmlTemplate.headers = headers;
    htmlTemplate.item = item;
    htmlTemplate.spec = spec;
    htmlTemplate.sat = sat;
    htmlTemplate.qty = qty;
    htmlTemplate.price = price;
    htmlTemplate.total = total;
    htmlTemplate.tujuan = tujuan;
    htmlTemplate.tableRangeValues = tableRangeValues;
    htmlTemplate.trigger = trigger;
    htmlTemplate.statusEmail = statusEmail;

    const htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
    Logger.log(trigger);
    if ((trigger != 'FALSE') && (statusEmail != 'EMAIL_SENT')) {
        GmailApp.sendEmail(
      "sistem.jis@gmail.com", 
      "Approval SPP Komersial", 
      "HTML Support",
      { htmlBody: htmlForEmail }
      );

      ws.getRange(3, 13,lr-2).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** 
In this sample I did not modify `tableRangeValues` since those values are processed later on on your client-side. Depending on what you want them to be like, you might also want to iterate throguh tem.

Comment: hi ziganotschka, thankyou for ur answer. I try to define each row like this one. But won't running with existing code

'const startRow = 3;
  const getLastRow = 900;
  const dataRange = ws.getRange(startRow, 1, getLastRow, 13);
  const data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    const row = data[i];
    const trigger = row[0];
    const statusEmail = row[12];'

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your new code? Would be easier to visualize.